# D3.js tooltip text stuck on first observation of csv

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a choropleth map using d3.js where each of the map's paths has a tooltip that pops up upon mouseover. I would like the tooltip to include information related to the path (in this case that information would be a rating for the given district).

The code I'm using below works well with the exception that the tooltip is stuck on the first row of the input csv. For example, if I hover over District 1 the tooltip will correctly display the district's rating. When I hover over District 2 it still only shows the data for District 1. This occurs even if the first district I hover over is a district besides District 1. In other words, the tooltip is stuck on District 1 indefinitely.

What am I missing here? Thanks for your advice in advance.

Here's a sample of the `ratings.csv` data:

```
"District","Rating"
"1","Hot"
"2","Cold"
"3","Cold"
"4","Hot"
```

And here's a sample of the topojson:

```
"objects":{"districts":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"arcs":[[0,1,2]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"District":"1"}}
```

And here's the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="map-div">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var width = 500;
            var height = 700;

            var map = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                .append("div") 
                .attr("class", "tooltip")       
                .style("opacity", 0);

            Promise.all([
                d3.json("districts.json"),  
                d3.csv("ratings.csv", function(d) {
                    return {
                        District: d.District,
                        Rating: d.Rating
                    }
                }) 
            ])
            .then(function(data){

            console.log(data)

            var conus = topojson.feature(data[0], {
                type:"GeometryCollection",
                geometries: data[0].objects.districts.geometries
            });

            var projection = d3.geoConicConformal()
                .parallels([38 + 20 / 60, 39 + 50 / 60])
                .rotate([122, 0])
                .fitExtent([[0,0],[630,700]], conus);

            var path = d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection);

            var ratings_map = d3.map()

            data[1].forEach(function(d){
                ratings_map.set(d["District"], 
                {"Rating" : d["Rating"]});
                });

            var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                .domain(["Cold", "Hot"])
                .range(["#11ede9", "#ed4011"]);

            map.selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(data[0], data[0].objects.districts).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "map-border")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.selectAll("path")
                    .style("opacity", .5)
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("cursor", "pointer")
                    .style("opacity", 1)
                    .style("stroke-width", "3px")
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .raise();
                })
            .on('mousemove', function (d) {
                tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 550) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 8) + "px")
                    .data(data[1])
                    .text(function(d) {
                        console.log(d)
                        return d.Rating
                    })
                tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .style("opacity", 1);
                })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                tooltip.transition()
                    .style("visibility", "hidden");
                d3.selectAll("path")
                    .style("opacity", 1)
                d3.select(this)
                    .style("stroke-width", "0.75px")
                    .style("stroke", "white")
                    .style("opacity", 1)
                    .style("cursor", "default")
                    .attr("fill", function() {
                        let district = ratings_map.get(d.properties.DISTRICT);
                        return colorScale(district["Rating"]);
                });         
            }) 
            .attr("fill", function(d){ 
                let district = ratings_map.get(d.properties.DISTRICT);
                return colorScale(district["Rating"]);
            });
        });

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please add `districts.json` and `ratings.csv` to your question, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I can post some sample data. Standby.

Comment: sure, or if you could add a link to those two files or something if possible.

Comment: Okay, the csv and topojson samples are posted. I'm hoping more topojson isn't required. Didn't want to post a big file full of coordinates and arcs!

Comment: can you add the full topojson, the one you add is not working.